# Eclipse with ADT - adb.exe keeps running even after IDE exit

Tags: android, eclipse, android-studio

When Eclipse with ADT exits, adb.exe keeps running.
Is there some Eclipse configuration setting to make sure adb.exe exits when Eclipse exits?

Environment: Windows 8.1, Eclipse adt-bundle-windows-x86_64-20140321.

This is an issue when when switching between Eclipse and Android Studio.  To avoid all sorts of error messages, this is what I have to do: [1] Kill first app (say Eclipse) [2] Manually kill adb.exe in Task Manager  [3] Start second app (say Android Studio).

Answer (score 1):

AFAIK adb is a client-server system; it keeps a server running even if noone is connected to the device. You can issue the command adb kill-server to force it to shut down, but Android Studio should automatically detect the adb server process that is already running. Do you have 2 ADT installations?

Comment: Only 1 ADT instance running. It just doesn't seem to play nicely if you run Eclipse and then AndroidStudio (or vice versa). Second app hangs, or gives multiple error message.  So I do the 3 steps described in my original post.